# Line Messenger API - Resolve sticker

Tags: line-api

I'm writing a small chat tool integrating with Line. One issue I'm facing is to display stickers sent by users from Line. In Line's webhook [documentation about sticker](https://devdocs.line.me/en/#webhook-event-object), only a package Id and sticker Id are provided.

```
{
    "replyToken": "nHuyWiB7yP5Zw52FIkcQobQuGDXCTA",
    "type": "message",
    "timestamp": 1462629479859,
    "source": {
        "type": "user",
        "userId": "U206d25c2ea6bd87c17655609a1c37cb8"
    },
    "message": {
        "id": "325708",
        "type": "sticker",
        "packageId": "1",
        "stickerId": "1"
    }
}
```

I only found a [sticker list pdf file](https://devdocs.line.me/files/sticker_list.pdf) in Line's official site to provide a very manual map between sticker ids and the actual sticker. Is there any online sticker store I can simply compose a web URL base on the package Id and sticker Id to reference to?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: it seems impossible https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-nodejs/issues/8. But i tricked it by download basic stickers and store locally